# Are the brake/clutch levers on a (pre-2008) Ninja 250 supposed to be symmetric?

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki

I bought a used 2007 Kawasaki Ninja 250R a couple months ago.  I had a mechanic check it out first, and I've been riding it since with no issues.  The other day I noticed that the brake lever seems to be curled in at the end a bit more than the clutch lever.  Are these levers supposed to be perfectly symmetric?  (Inspired by [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/634/can-a-motorcycles-brake-lever-be-bent-back-into-shape).)

It's very low mileage, and there's no evidence that it's ever been laid down on that side.  It doesn't pose any problem when riding, and in fact I didn't even notice this for a couple of weeks, nor did my mechanic.  It seems perfectly sturdy still -- just in a slightly different shape than the clutch lever.

This isn't bad, is it?

Comment: It's also possible that it's been dumped and "most" of the damages were covered up/repaired, except for the clutch lever.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a sign its been tipped. Probably not at speed though because the lever would be rashed. Unless its a comfort issue for you leave it be. If you are a perfectionist they are cheap on ebay or at your local cyclegear.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Honda Magna that was knocked over from being parked on two separate occasions.  Both times it happened to fall on the clutch side and it curled up the clutch lever.  I think this is by design as no other damage was done and I just had to replace the lever.

If yours is only bent slightly it might have fallen over at some point but not as hard (I am guessing this is a lighter bike).  They are typically easy to replace and cheap. I would suggest looking up a new lever and if a new one is not curved then just replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing on my 08 ninja 500, the seller obviously laid it down on the left side so it had a "curled" clutch. A new one cost me $7 and I replaced it myself, so not a big deal.